# Wix - relationship between heatdirectory directory and preprocessorvariable

Tags: visual-studio, wix, installation, heat

I am using heat to harvest my project but am confused about the relationship between the defined preprocessor variable in visual studio like: `SourceDir=$(SolutionDir)MyProject`, the <`HeatDirectory> Directory=var.SourceDir` and `<HeatDirectory> Directory=$(SolutionDir)MyProject`

Which one is defining the source directory which is going to be harvested? To me it looks like preprocessorvariable/defined preprocessor variable in VS are overwriting the Directory one in HeadDirectory.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to clear up, when you call `heat`, the directory you harvest will be supplied via the command line argument to `heat`. The `SourceDir` is a placeholder for the path in which you'd find the actual files harvested, relative to the directory that you chose to harvest.

It's defined by a preprocessor variable or by a path you specify to `light` using the `-b` option.

When you call `heat`, you can tell it which variable to replace `SourceDir` with and when you call `candle`, you'll define it.

An example:

```
heat dir [options] -var var.MyProjectDir <dir to harvest>
```

will produce a .wxs file with `$(var.MyProjectDir)` in place of `SourceDir`

When you call `candle`:

```
candle [options] -dMyProjectDir=<my project path> <wxs files>
```

Using the `-d` option will allow you to define the value of the preprocessor variable and reference it when you compile your fragment files.

If you don't use the `-var` and `-d` options to `heat` and `candle`, you can use `-b` in `light` and WiX will use that to attempt to resolve files using those paths. It essentially acts like your environment PATH variable, in that it will use all paths specified to find files.